# How can I vertically center divs in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, vertical-alignment

I am working on a project that requires me to vertically center divs. I have three columns of with the size col-s-4. The two columns on the left and right are static, while the column in the middle is scrollable.

I have two textboxes in the right and left columns that need to be responsive in the middle of the page. I don't really know how to get the divs center up. I've been trying various Bootstrap tricks, such as column offset or using the "vertical-center" class, but nothing really seems to be working.

This is what I was trying to use, but it is not currently working:

```
.text-div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: table;
 }
```

Here's a link to my CodePen so you can see what I need to accomplish.

https://codepen.io/anfperez/pen/rJzmMM

Comment: Your codepen has both Bootstrap 3.3.7 and 4 referenced.

Comment: @TomMichew I'm sorry, could you tell me where? All i see is references to 3.3.7